# Как парсить не все ссылки на видео?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Есть парсер, который переходит по ссылкам, которые он берет из csv-файла и парсит с этих страниц видео, но есть одна проблема: если на странице несколько видео, то он парсит все видео, а мне надо, чтобы он парсил только первое видео.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

FILE="games.csv"

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    r.encoding = 'utf8'
    return r.text



def get_link(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    video = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "highlight_player_item", "data-mp4-hd-source": True})

    for item in video:
        games.append({'video':item["data-mp4-hd-source"]})



def save_file(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='', encoding='cp1251') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['VIDEOS','LINK'])
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([item['video']])
games=[]
with open("racesru.csv", newline='', encoding='cp1251') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        link = row[4]
        if (link != '0' and link != 'LINK'):
            url = link
            print(url)
            save_file(games, FILE)
            get_link(get_html(str(url)))
```

Comment: soup.find_all() ищет все, замените на метод bs4, который найдет только первый

Comment: @Jack_oS можно поподробнее, если не трудно, я просто только учусь и еще не разбираюсь в этой теме

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно ограничить цикл добавления в `games` [срезом](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
def get_link(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    video = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "highlight_player_item", "data-mp4-hd-source": True})

    for item in video[1:]:
        games.append({'video': item["data-mp4-hd-source"]})
```

video[1:] - от второго элеманта и до конца,
или брать только первую ссылку на видео методом [.find()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find):

```
def get_link(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    video = soup.find('div', attrs={"class": "highlight_player_item", "data-mp4-hd-source": True})

    games.append({'video': video["data-mp4-hd-source"]})
```